# Height issue in ios devices with Hybrid app

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework

I am using ionic for application.I have one ionic modal in my app.When i am setting height in px or percentage its coming correct for all android device but not for ios.If i use .platform-ios  for height in CSS for ios devices its not coming same for all ios devices.
I have added vh for ios but still not same for all ios devices.What can i do can anyone suggest me.

css:-

```
 .appModal
{
   height:120px;
}

.platform-ios .appModal
{
   height:40vh;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I might have not understood what exactly you're trying to ask, but the whole point of `%` and `vh` is to be relative to the device width and height, respectively.  So it has to be different for different devices

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

You can see that iOS 9.3 Safari and above support the Viewport Height and Width measurements `vh` and `vw`

Older iOS devices don't support these, see the known issues tab on that link for more information.

As a fallback you can use something like:

```
.class-name {
  height: 300px;
  height: 40vh;
}
```

Browsers that support `vh` will use specified `40vh` but older browsers/devices will see theres an error and default back to the `300px` height.

> **Please note:** more widely supported css should appear first in your markup. Otherwise you won't be able to overwrite for the newer browser.

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue too ;
the best solutions i found is to use javascript is supported every where ;)
code be something like this :

```
  var heighDevice = window.screen.height;
  var FirstELement = document.getElementById('MyAppModal');//MyAppModal id element 
  var heightElm = (heighDevice  * 40) / 100; // 40 is height in vh  
  // add the height to the element
  FirstELement.style["height"] =  heightElm + "px";
```